# How to pass environment variable to sh script?

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I want to create an environment variable in Jenkinsfile which will consist of current workspace (using envirnoment variable WORKSPACE). Then I want to pass this new variable to sh script in next stage.

I've tried declaring variable in the following way:

```
environment {
        artefact_path = "${env.WORKSPACE}/temp/unzipped/${artefact_name}/dev"
    }
```

But after passing it to sh script:

```
sh "ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e \"artefact_path=${env.artefact_path}\""
```

I get the following output:

```
+ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e 'artefact_path=C:\nowy_dir\workspace\something/temp/unzipped/something/dev'
PLAY [play] **************************************************************

TASK [task] *********************************************************
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "D:/inetpub/something", "msg": "Get-AnsibleParam: Parameter 'src' has an invalid path 'C:\nowy_dir\\workspace\\something/temp/unzipped/something/dev' specified.", "src": "C:\nowy_dir\\workspace\\something/temp/unzipped/something/dev"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/ansible-scripts/playbook.retry
```

As you can see the variable is passed with two \ instead of one. How can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT 1**

I decided to change the way in which I declare the variable to:

```
def get_deploy_path() {
    def site = get_site()
    def wspace = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
    def deploy_path = wspace.toString() + "\\temp\\snapshot\\" + site + "\\"
    return deploy_path
}
```

```
environment {
        deploy_path = get_deploy_path()
}
```

Now I have a problem with workspace. I'm operating on two agents (first is Windows and the second is Linux based). I need the path to be the same both in stages on Windows and on Linux. Any idea how I can make it happen?

Comment: Are you aware you have forward slashes in this windows path ?

Comment: Yes I'm aware - even though I've changed the forward to backword slashes I still get 
C:\nowy_dir\\workspace\\something\temp\\unzipped\\something\\dev"

Problem here is with the doubling of slashes.

Comment: @Zeitounator: AFAIK, Windows can accept both